# Bot hosted in Azure with Google Vision Api - gRPC issue

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, grpc, vision-api

Trying to use Google Vision Api from Bot Framework app hosted on Azure. The code works just fine on local but I get this error when I try it on Azure. Can someone help?

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\grpc_extension.js:38:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10).
```

Here is the package.json that I am using:

```
  {
  "name": "luisbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^0.10.0",
    "botbuilder": "^3.7.0",
    "botbuilder-azure": "3.0.2",
    "botbuilder-location": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "restify": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and the error throws while loading the vision api module -  at the line mention below

```
var vision = require('@google-cloud/vision')
```

Comment: Could you provide the `package.json` file on your question?

Comment: **Hi Aaron - Here is the package.json file:**


`{
  "name": "luisbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^0.10.0",
    "botbuilder": "^3.7.0",
    "botbuilder-azure": "3.0.2",
    "botbuilder-location": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "restify": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}`

Comment: facing the same issue only with @google-cloud/pubsub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, using grpc modules from inside the function code is not supported as Functions runtime uses [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/) for executing JavaScript code and it does not have support for loading native modules. Related [issue](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/518).

Comment: any ETA to adding this ability? right now it's blocking us from using some packages (like @google-cloud/pubsub) , thanks

Comment: We are working on moving away from edge. I do not have exact ETA yet. But you can track the feature [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1319)